# Angular 2 - how to display the array object inside an array of objects

Tags: angular

This is my example of json file

```
{
    "id": 5,
    "url": "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/users/5/",
    "username": "Najmuddin",
    "email": "",
    "groups": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "url": "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/groups/1/",
        "name": "KETUA UNIT SEKSYEN",
        "permissions": [
          "Can add level",
          "Can change level",
          "Can delete level"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
```

and this is my code

```
public getUser(){
  this.jobService.getUsers().subscribe(
    user => {
      for (let i = 0; i < user.length; i++) {
        this.user = user;
        let username = user[i].username; --> i can get id,url,username,...
        let group = user[i].groups; --> i only get the [object] but i want 
         to get the id, url, and name instead
      }
    },
  );
}
```

I only can get and display object for User and not be able to get groups id, url and name `and permission`[object]`. Is it something that i missing?

Comment: how does `jobService.getUsers()` looks like? is this the json it returns?

Comment: @OferHerman Yes.. it returns the json API that i give as the example above

Comment: In your example code, you are assigning an array of groups to your variable. You might want to use something like this: `let groups = user[i].groups; for (let group of groups) {...}`

Comment: @alexkucksdorf can you elaborate more.. i don't get the idea.

Comment: In your `getUser()` method, if you would log your variable `group` it would probably print `[object object]` or something like that. That is because it contains an array of objects. If you want to access the properties of one specific group, you need to either iterate over your array like I suggested before, or you can specifically access it via `group[x].url`

Comment: @alexkucksdorf yes,, it print `[object object]` i have tried something like `group[a].url` and i got `undefined` .

Comment: The problem might be that your array is empty. Have you tried logging the size of the array? Just to make sure that it isn't empty.

Comment: @alexkucksdorf yes,, i just try it and my array is not empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code

```
userlist: any;
public getUser(){
  this.jobService.getUsers().subscribe(
    user => {
      this.userlist=user;
      for (let i = 0; i < user.length; i++) {
        let username = this.userlist[i].username;
        let group = this.userlist[i].groups;
        let id = this.userlist[i].groups[0]?.id;
        let url = this.userlist[i].groups[0]?.url;
       console.log("********* start *******");
       console.log(username);
       console.log(group);
       console.log(id);
       console.log(url);
       console.log("********* end *******");
      }
    },
  );
}
```

put console.log(this.username) if console.log(username) show you undefined. and remove ? if you are sure that group array is not empty

for *ngFor you can do like this

```
  <div *ngFor="let user of userlist">
       <p>{{user.username}} - {{user.group[0]?.id}} -{{user.groups[0]?.url}}<p>
  </div>
```

Comment: wow.. it works.. but how do i display it in my tempate using ngFor?

Comment: and i got this error `Cannot read property 'url' of undefined`

Comment: @uetoaya you are getting url undefined because some of your json may not have any url. answer edited with *ngFor also. use *ngIf="user.group[0].url" if safe naviagtion ? not work.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to do a nested ngFor

```
<div *ngFor="let user of userlist">
    <p>{{user.username}}<p>
    <p *ngFor="let group of user.groups">{{group.id}} ...<p>
</div>
```

this way if user.groups is not populated you won't have an error.

Answer (score 0):

there is no need to subscribe you can display the list using `Observable`

```js
 public let users$: Observable<any>;

 public getUser(){
    users$ = this.jobService.getUsers();
}
```

and in your view:

```
<div *ngFor='let user of users | async'>
    <p>{{user.id}}</p>
    <p>{{user.name}}</p>
    <p>{{user.email}}</p>
    <p>{{user.url}}</p>
    <h2>groups:</h3>
    <div *ngFor='let group of user.groups'>
         <p>{{group.id}}</p>
         <p>{{group.name}}</p>
         <p>{{group.url}}</p>
         <h3>Permissions:</h3>
         <div *ngFor='let permission of group.permissions'>
             <p>{{permission}}</p>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

my json data is this

```js
 "orders": [
        {
            "totalPrice": 1200,
            "_id": "5cf0b8fd245b7904440aa4b7",
            "products": [
                {
                    "quantity": 1,
                    "_id": "5cf0b8fd245b7904440aa4b8",
                    "product": {
                        "reviews": [
                            "5cf0b8a8245b7904440aa4b6"
                        ],
                        "_id": "5ce83a9c16bec823d4bddff9",
                        "crated": "2019-05-24T18:40:28.253Z",
                        "owner": "5cc2f1c195d5a13018080651",
                        "category": "5cc62714304f84437059eada",
                        "title": "book",
                        "price": 12,
                        "description": "aaaaaaaa",
                        "image": "uploads\\1558723228216-direct-to-other-schema.png",
                        "__v": 1,
                        "averageRating": null,
                        "id": "5ce83a9c16bec823d4bddff9"
                    }
                }
            ],
```

and in an angular template, I get data like this

```html
<div *ngFor="let order of orders" class="order">
  <div *ngFor="let product of order.products" class="orders">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4 col-md-2">
        <a routerLink="/order/{{ order.id }}">
          <img src="http://localhost:3030/{{ product.product.image }}" alt="image" class="img-fluid img-thumbnail">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-5 col-md-8">
        <h5>
          <a routerLink="/orders/{{ order.id }}">{{ product.product.title }}</a>
          <p class="m-0">
            <small class="text-muted">{{ product.product.category }}</small>
          </p>
        </h5>
      </div>
      <div class="col-2">
        <h6 class="font-weight-bold text-danger">{{ order.totalPrice | currency }}</h6>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr>
</div>
```